# Selecting Date Range on a PHP form and displaying results from MySQL database

Tags: php

This may be something simple but I cant understand why this wouldn't work..

I have a php form where you can select a date range from drop downs. I've given the field names day, month year, and day1, month1, year1.

When clicking submit it takes you to a second php form. Here is the code for second form:

```
<?php

$username="***";
$password="***";
$database="****";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$day = $_GET['day'];
$month = $_GET['month'];
$year = $_GET['year'];
$day1 = $_GET['day1'];
$month1 = $_GET['month1'];
$year1 = $_GET['year1'];

$date1 = "$year-$month-$day";
$date2 = "$year1-$month1-$day1";

$query = "SELECT * FROM main_stock WHERE curr_timestamp BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_num_rows($result); 

?>

<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Product Description</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Category</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Master Category</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Barcode</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Status</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">TimeStamp</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">New Own</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Serial No.</font></b></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"product_desc");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"category");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"mastercategory");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"barcode");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"status");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"curr_timestamp");
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"newown");
$f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"serial");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f8; ?></font></td>
</tr>


<?php



$i++;
}
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Is there any reason this wouldn't work?

I'm not sure where I am going wrong. It displays results when there is another option as well as the date such as 'status' but when this is taken out and I just want to display all the results between the date range it doesn't work..

This works:

```
<?php

$username="+++";
$password="+++";
$database="+++";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$day = $_GET['day'];
$month = $_GET['month'];
$year = $_GET['year'];
$day1 = $_GET['day1'];
$month1 = $_GET['month1'];
$year1 = $_GET['year1'];
$status = $_GET['status'];

$date1 = "$year-$month-$day";
$date2 = "$year1-$month1-$day1";

$query = "SELECT * FROM main_stock WHERE status = '$status' AND curr_timestamp BETWEEN      '$date1' AND '$date2'";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_num_rows($result); 

?>

<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Product Description</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Category</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Master Category</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Barcode</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Status</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">TimeStamp</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">New Own</font></b></td>
<td><b><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Serial No.</font></b></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"product_desc");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"category");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"mastercategory");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"barcode");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"status");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"curr_timestamp");
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"newown");
$f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"serial");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f8; ?></font></td>
</tr>


<?php



$i++;
}
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
mysql_close();
?>
```

But when the 'status' field is taken out (and obviously the serial drop down in the first form) it stops working...

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the output of `$query` and do you get an error?

Comment: I don't get an error is just doesn't display the results

Comment: When you say results , which results?
You know you need to have a `echo` for the variable you want to print - right?

Comment: Yeah that's just after the code i've shown, but I know the print section is correct is just this php section that seems to be wrong

Comment: Are you aware that there's no function named 'mysql_numrows'?
Did you mean `mysql_num_rows`?

Comment: Its only when I take the 'serial' field out of this php script that it stops working

Comment: I have made some edits to the question above, I can't understand why when the serial field is taken out it stops working?

Comment: That's really weird. We're missing here something. Tip1) Try to `echo` the variables in order to check their value. Tip2) Share the rest of the code Tip3) What do you mean when you're saying 'stop working

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I've added the rest of the code. The 'status' code displays all the results from the database based on the date range given and the staus. When the status is taken out no results are displayed when it should still display all the results between the dates given

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link - will start to use PDO but how do I get this form to display the results from the date range?

Answer (score 0):

1) Please use PDO or at the very least `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$date` and `$date1`.

2) Make sure you form is being sent via `GET`. If it is `POST` you should be using `$_POST['...']` instead of `$_GET`.

3) Make sure your dates are in the correct format. You can do this using sprintf.

```
$date = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $year, $month, $day);
$date1 = sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $year1, $month1, $day1);
```

4) Make sure `curr_timestamp` is a valid date/time field type.

Comment: this not a answer, but a comment

Comment: Maybe but there was too much to fit in a comment. There are also some answer worthy notes in there.

Comment: My form is being sent by $_GET and curr_timestamp is a valid date. The form works when I add a drop down to select 'serial' in the first form and the correct lines in the second form but when this is taken out and left with just the dates it doesn't work..

Comment: Please could somebody tell me a possible cause for the above question and a solution - unfortunately this is still not working?

Comment: @SarahHSL can you add some error reporting after the $result = ... line: if (!$result) { echo mysql_error(); die(); }

Comment: I have added the error reporting line but the page doesn't display an error but still displays no results?

Comment: @SarahHSL I really can't see what would be causing this. Try putting parenthesis around the between statement: $query = "SELECT * FROM main_stock WHERE curr_timestamp BETWEEN ('$date1' AND '$date2')"; The only other explanation would be that your tests do not contain the same data, ie the two dates are different on each script.